# Remove duplicates from DropDownList from database MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I would like to take data from DB and add it to `DropDownList` in order to select an item in search panel, I want to remove duplicates items from the list (one author, many books). What should I do?

```
List<string> authorname = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in DB.Books)
{
    authorname.Add(item.BookDetails.authorname.ToString());
}

ViewData["AuthorName"] = new SelectList(authorname);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
List<string> authorname = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in DB.Books)
{
   if(!authorname.Contains(item.BookDetails.authorname.ToString()))
      authorname.Add(item.BookDetails.authorname.ToString());
}

ViewData["AuthorName"] = new SelectList(authorname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Populate the DropDownList with unique values after they have been already selected from the database. Use the 'distinct' keyword in your SQL query in order to achieve this goal.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> authorname = new List<string>();
foreach (string name in DB.Books.Select(x=> new {name = x.authorname}).Distinct())
{
   authorname.Add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use linq and get the distinct items ..

code here

```
list<string> authorNamesDistinct = (from a in DB.Books
select a.BookDetails.authorname).Distinct().ToList();


ViewData["AuthorName"] = new SelectList(authorNamesDistinct);
```